# What is the difference between ex ante and a priori, if any?

Tags: estimation, terminology

In the context of estimating geophysical quantities from remotely sensed data (inverse theory), what do the terms *ex ante* and *ex post* mean?  For context, see for example [this paper by T. von Clarmann](http://www.atmos-chem-phys.net/6/4311/2006/acp-6-4311-2006.html) (emphasis mine):

> The actual value of $χ^2$ allows to conclude if the differences $\mathbf{\hat{x}}_\textrm{val} - \mathbf{\hat{x}}_\textrm{ref}$ are consistent with the **ex ante** estimates of the uncertainties of the difference, represented by its covariance matrix $\mathbf{S}_\textrm{diff}$ , or if there is a significant inconsistency.

and:

> Instead, we use independent reference measurements, which allow to infer **ex post** estimates of bias, precision, and accuracy.

Is there any difference between the terms *ex ante* and *a priori*?
Likewise, is there a difference between *ex post* and *a posteriori*?
If yes, what are those differences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*Ex ante*" & "*ex post*" are used in forecasting:

An *ex ante* forecast uses only the information available at a given time to predict what'll happen after that time.

An *ex post* forecast also uses information available after the given time.

So while an *ex post* sales forecast based on GDP growth in a region may be informative, the *ex ante* sales forecast for practical application will need to be based on forecasts of future GDP growth.

Answer (score 5):

*Ex Ante* means *before the event*. *Ex Post* means *after the event*. In this example, I think this means before and after the event that gives the statistical difference you're testing, respectively.

On the other hand, *a priori* and *a posteriori* are terms from philosophy, respectively denoting knowledge that is logically derived, and knowledge that requires empirical evidence. ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_priori_and_a_posteriori))

Comment: What *event* would that be?  And *a priori* and *a posteriori* do have a rather specific meaning in (Bayesian) statistics too.

Answer (score 0):

To me, there is a meaning of process in the term a priori: a priori, I think so, but my mind might change through the process of understanding of the new ideas. However, ex ante refers to a moment that is right before an event: ex ante Wall Street fell down, I sold my assets.